# extracting string between labels using regex

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following string

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r100 | dawson | 2012-10-3 04:21:27 -0600 (Wed, 3 Oct 2012) | 8 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/project/foo.cpp
   A /branches/project/foo1.cpp
   D /branches/project/foo2.cpp

:SUMMARY: Add new file
:Module:

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now what I am trying to do is, make list of all the files that have changed for a particular commit. For that I first need to extract the information between label "Changed paths:" and ":SUMMARY:" , well the regex solution I have is not very neat. When I do,

```
set blocks [regexp -nocase -lineanchor -inline -all -- {^\s*?Changed paths\s*?:\s*?.*?:} $summary]
```

where $summary is the string content above, my output is,

```
{Changed paths:
   M /branches/project/foo.cpp
   A /branches/project/foo1.cpp
   D /branches/project/foo2.cpp

:}
```

Expected output:

```
   M /branches/project/foo.cpp
   A /branches/project/foo1.cpp
   D /branches/project/foo2.cpp
```

I cant seem to get rid of "Changed paths:" . I dont have lot of experience with this, can anyone point out what am I doing wrong, and if there is a way to store those changed files in a list may be?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew I added the expected output. Basically, I want the changed files information, if I could get them in a list, even better

Comment: See http://ideone.com/QvUi7h

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the part of the regex pattern that fetches the substring you need with *capturing* parentheses, and then specify a variable that will hold the value in `regexp`:

```
Changed paths\s*?:\s*?(.*?):SUMMARY
                      ^^^^^
```

See the demo below:

```
set summary {------------------------------------------------------------------------
r100 | dawson | 2012-10-3 04:21:27 -0600 (Wed, 3 Oct 2012) | 8 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/project/foo.cpp
   A /branches/project/foo1.cpp
   D /branches/project/foo2.cpp

:SUMMARY: Add new file
:Module:

------------------------------------------------------------------------}
regexp {\n\s*?Changed paths\s*?:\s*?(.*?):SUMMARY} $summary - blocks
puts $blocks
```

See the [Tcl online demo](http://ideone.com/QvUi7h)

If the `Changed paths` appears at the start of a string, use `^` instead of `\n`.

The `$summary - blocks` means: we pass `$summary` string to the `regexp`, and discard the whole match value (`-`) and assign the Capture group 1 contents to the `$blocks` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use (based on your example)

```
regexp -nocase -line -inline -all {^\s+.*$} $summary
```

or

```
regexp -nocase -line -inline -all {^.*\.cpp$} $summary
```